# Git creates an extra file with my machine name appended at the end

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I've just altered a file and successfully  committed it and pushed it and everything is fine from that point of view but  when I go back into the master branch it seems to have created an extra yaml file...exactly the same as the one I've just pushed but this time it has my machine name appended to the end of it...

It started off looking like this  .`gitlab-ci-yml`....but it's now created an extra one called .`gitlab-ci-mikeslaptop.yaml` in the same folder ...and posh git says  `[master = +1 ~0 -0 !]`  and git says `untracked files (use "git add ,file>..." to include in what will be committed) .gitlab-ci-mikeslaptop.yaml`

Has anyone ever seen this behaviour before..I'm goggling but finding nothing.
any help gratefully received

Comment: That’s a gitlab thing, not git (maybe you were alluding to that with ‘’’git posh’’’) See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/gitlab_ci_yaml.html for documentation.

Comment: This sounds molre some file that your editor created, given also that is on your PC, and not on GitLab. Which editor do you use?